# What variables do I have to introduce in my ecommerce tracking code?

Tags: e-commerce, analytics, tracking

I have to enter the e-commerce tracking code and collect data, and no matter how many tutorials I see, I only get this:

```
gtag('event', 'purchase', {
  "transaction_id": "24.031608523954162",
  "affiliation": "Google online store",
  "value": 23.07,
  "currency": "USD",
  "tax": 1.24,
  "shipping": 0,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "P12345",
      "name": "Android Warhol T-Shirt",
      "list_name": "Search Results",
      "brand": "Google",
      "category": "Apparel/T-Shirts",
      "variant": "Black",
      "list_position": 1,
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": '2.0'
    },
    {
      "id": "P67890",
      "name": "Flame challenge TShirt",
      "list_name": "Search Results",
      "brand": "MyBrand",
      "category": "Apparel/T-Shirts",
      "variant": "Red",
      "list_position": 2,
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": '3.0'
    }
  ]
});
```

As your can see, in the tutorials they use invented data as an example, but they don't indicate how to make these variables collect data from the site without having to enter it manually.

Can someone tell me how I can collect this data from my site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make this dynamic, you can have your own structure with whatever fields you want, for example:

```
 var purchase_data = {
    send: google_id,
    category: "ecommerce",
    transaction_id: order.transaction_id,
    value: order.value,
    currency: order.currency,
    shipping: order.shipping
}
```

and then:

```
gtag('event', 'purchase', purchase_data);
```